# Can i join two C# DataTables on a common column

Tags: c#, datatable

I have two DataTables dt1 and dt2. Each table have different data in them but they have a common column ReportID.

Is there a way of joining the datatables similar to a SQL Inner Join?

I have tried using DataRelation but it didn't work

Thanks

Comment: why did the data relation not work. post some code and the issue you faced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load your data tables into a DataSet and then you are free to create relations and query the data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ss7fbaez.aspx

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for that i did look at Datasets but it was creating a hierachical set 

i managed to use Linq for it but am now facing an issue of converting my result set into a DataTable to bind to my gridview source

var results = from r in dtReports.AsEnumerable()
        join c in dtReportDetail.AsEnumerable() on r.Field<int>("ReportID") equals c.Field<int>("ReportID")
        select new List<object>(r.ItemArray).Concat(c.ItemArray);

   DataTable dtCombineTables = results.CopyToDataTable<DataTable>();

the CopyToDataTable method doesn't get recognised

Comment: Take a look here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aconrad/archive/2007/09/07/science-project.aspx

Comment: Simple as that:

// load into new DataTable
DataTable dtCombineTables = result.CopyToDataTable();